# Help please! What is wrong with my Betta fish?

Tags: health, fish, betta

My betta fish seems to be sick and has been like that for the past two weeks. He spends most of the day laying at the bottom of the tank and is not responsive. He goes up for air occasionally and is still eating.

I thought maybe he had swim bladder disease so I did not feed him for 3 days, but he did not get better. I noticed his color is not the same and his fins look rugged, so I assumed it was fin rot. I changed the water and gave him antibiotic for 7 days but he isn’t any better.

I’m having a hard time diagnosing him and figuring out how to treat him at this point. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: welcome to stackexchange :) there are a lots of questions similar to yours if you search for "sick beta". Look if you find some answers in there. If not, then write more details in your question so we could see the difference to the other questions. I know the fish experts here do always want you to make a water test, so you should post the results of it in your question too.